# Best way to save horoscope data

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, content

I'm workin on a website that's goin to have two horoscope sections:

1. The normal zodiac - Updated weekly
2. The chinese horoscope - Updated yearly

#### The Normal Zodiac

This section will have pages for each sign of the zodiac with informations like **current week forecast**, color, gem, best month day and etc.

#### The Chinese Horoscope

This section will have pages for each sign of the zodiac with informations that will be updated once a year and will have informations like color, gem and etc. as well

## The question

Should I create a **custom post-type** for each type of zodiac and create single posts for every sign or maybe I can fit all this information inside a good **Pages** structure?

And what about some **custom taxonomies** to hold the color, gem, and extra info of each sign? I don't think it's a good idea because there's no search form, filter or something like that to use these informations as taxonomies.

What do you guys think it's a good way to store this data without abusing of the system and - yet - keeping it easly maintanble for the site owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would handle this with 2 custom post types and then a few custom taxonomies, depending on what kind of organization you want on that.

I would use one custom post type for each horoscope (normal vs chinese) and then each would have a taxonomy for sign (separate taxonomies, not the same taxonomy for the two).

If the gems and such are common between the horoscopes (I'm not familiar with astrology), then I would make those a non-hierarchical taxonomy (one each, so one for gems, one for color, etc). This will allow flexibility in terms of queries on them and such and will allow intermingling of chinese and normal sections in searches/listings, which should encourage users to read both and keep them on the site longer.